# Old version of minitest used when running unit tests through rake

Tags: ruby, macos, rake, minitest

I have some classes with unit tests and I have a rake task to run these unit tests. However, I'm running into a problem where when the tests are run via rake an old version of minitest is being used. How can I get rake to use the newer version?

If I use the `Minitest::Test` subclass it runs fine when the tests are directly run through the `ruby`
command-line. However, if I use the following rake task:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = 'tests/**/*_test.rb'
end
```

When I check the minitest version using `puts MiniTest::Unit::VERSION` it prints 5.5.0 when run with ruby, but prints 4.3.2 when run with rake. (When using `gem list minitest -d` version 4.3.2 is listed as the default.)

The reason I want to use the newer version of minitest is that when I directly run the unit tests using Ruby 2.0 I get the following warning:

```
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test.
```

However, if I change `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase` to `Minitest::Test` I get the following error when I run the tests using rake.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant MiniTest::Test (NameError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:28:in `const_missing'
```

I want to avoid requiring any changes to the system configuration, because I want these tests to run on the default OS X ruby installation.

Using `gem 'minitest', '=5.5.0'` does not change the version of minitest that gets used.

Comment: Have you tried running Rake using bundle exec?  If you're specifying Minitest 5.5 in your Gemfile, that should force it to use that version.

Comment: @ChrisKottom That solution appears to work. It would be nice if there was a solution that worked without installing a gem. You should write up your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Possibility #1: Run Rake with `bundle exec` to force it to use the version of Minitest managed by Bundler:

```
bundle exec rake test
```

Possibility #2: Create a binstub for Rake for your project that will load your bundle automatically:

```
bundle binstub rake
```

After that, you should be able to run Rake without `bundle exec` to get the same result.

Caveat: This has worked for the Ruby environment managers I've used recently, but you might need to Google around for a solution if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is having a hard time loading minitest from the gem instead of the standard library, so we need to give it a little help. Add the following to your helper or rake task:

```
gem "minitest"
```

That will tell ruby to use the gem version. Just be sure to add that before minitest is required.

Comment: Strange. Doing this fixed the problem for one of my systems, but not for a different one.